# When should I do the grid search for SVM?

Tags: libsvm, grid-search, hyperparameters

I am using LibSVM for 3D medical image segmentation. I have a data set of 15 patient cases. From every patient case, I randomly select 1000 voxels as samples. I use the leave-one-out cross validation for patient cases so that there are 15 times of learning-testing.

In each procedure of the learning-testing, I use the grid search method to find best hyperparameter C and gamma. However, the grid search costs so much processing time that I am not able to use more samples to do training-testing.

My question is when I should do grid search to find best hyperparameter?

Some friend told me I only need to redo the grid search after I change the combination of features. However I don't feel safe about it. Because even in the 15 times of learning-testing, I can got several different pairs of best C and gamma, which merely results from 1/14 portion difference of training samples.

On the other hand, considering about over-fitting, I am wondering whether it is necessary to use exactly the best hyperparameter acquired from training data set. Can I use the hyperparameters I acquired in the previous and a little different experiments rather than to redo the time-consuming grid-search again?

Comment: Maybe the top answer to this [question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23509/fast-method-for-finding-best-metaparameters-of-svm-that-is-faster-than-grid-sea) can help you.

Comment: Thanks to @Monaj. Instead of the method to make grid search faster, I'm more interested in the necessity of hyperparameter resetting. When should I reset the hyperparameters through grid search? What if the dataset does not change that much, like the addition/removal of more samples from one class/patient case, the addition/removal of features?